# How to Detect Multiple Monitors in a Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I have recently started diving into writing Batch files and I have a question. I'm trying to create a file that checks to see if my secondary monitor is connected and than if it is switches the primary display to the secondary screen. (Yes I do know about the windows+P shortcut)...

So far I have figured out that "DisplaySwitch.exe /external" sets the default display to the secondary monitor but I cannot find out how to detect whether the display is there first.

-Cheers, Luke

Answer (score 3):

With Windows 10, may be just a call to:

```
 wmic desktopmonitor get DeviceID
```

output:

```
DeviceID
DesktopMonitor1
DesktopMonitor2
```

More details about monitor with :

```
 wmic desktopmonitor get
```

Comment: That's, what I would expect. But it seems to be unreliable. It shows only one device on my two-headed PC.

Comment: Yes, it happens to me too

Answer (score 2):

By calling a powershell from the cmd the following will get the number of monitors:

```
powershell -Command "exit (Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams | Select-String -Pattern 'InstanceName').length"
set nMons=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use [dxdiag](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/system/monitorInfo.bat) though it is not the fastest way:

```
@echo off

del ~.txt /q /f >nul 2>nul
dxdiag /t ~
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:3  >nul 2>&1
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set currmon=1 
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('find "Current Mode:" ~.txt') do (
    echo Monitor !currmon! : %%a
    set /a currmon=currmon+1

)
endlocal
del ~.txt /q /f >nul 2>nul
```

this will print the resolutions of all monitors.

**Update**:

dxdiag prints info about all monitors so you can check if there are more than one monitors:

```
@echo off
del ~.txt /q /f >nul 2>nul
start "" /w dxdiag /t ~

for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('find /c "Current Mode:" "~.txt"') do (
    set /a "number_of_monitors=%%b"
    rem echo #%%b#
)
rem exit /b 0
echo %number_of_monitors%


rem :---- if it needed -----:

if defined number_of_monitors ( if %number_of_monitors% GTR 1 ( echo second monitor connected ) else (echo only one monitor connected ))
del ~.txt /q /f >nul 2>nul
```

Comment: Okay, so this generates a file with all the specs of my computer... I'm asking how to make a batch file that checks if my secondary monitor is connected, than makes the secondary monitor the primary monitor. Am I missing your point?

Comment: @LukeRector - check my update.It prints a message if there more than one monitors.

Answer (score 1):

@npocmaka's answer didn't quite work for me, but this variation of his code did (Windows 10):

```
rem @echo off
del %TEMP%\dxdiag.txt /q /f >nul 2>nul
start "" /w dxdiag -64bit -t %TEMP%\dxdiag.txt

for /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /c"Monitor Name:" %TEMP%\dxdiag.txt') do set MONITOR_COUNT=%%f

if defined MONITOR_COUNT ( if %MONITOR_COUNT% GTR 1 ( echo second monitor connected ) else (echo only one monitor connected ))
del %TEMP%\monitors.txt /q /f >nul 2>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET monitors=monitors.txt
SET nMons=0
MultiMonitorTool.exe /scomma "%monitors%"
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=9 delims=," %%a IN (%monitors%) DO IF %%a GTR 0 SET /A nMons += 1
echo Number of monitors: %nMons%
```

[MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick way to get connected monitors count via powershell

```
$m = Get-PnpDevice -Class Monitor -Status OK | measure; $m.Count
```